# When referring to "every location" in Dead of Winter does this include the colony?

Tags: dead-of-winter

When a crossroad card says that something happens at every location does that include the colony? Does the colony by itself count as one location or do each of the numbered entrances count as a location?

Specific case: A card offers to draw two zombies away from every location. How many of them will be gone from the colony? Zero? Two? Up to twelve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Colony is a location with six entrances. So for instance Raiding Party says add two zombies to every location. This includes the colony which would get one zombie in Entrance 1 and one zombie in Entrance 2

In your specified case when taking away zombies you would again take only two from the colony not two from every entrance

From the manual page 5:

> The game board is made up of 7 different locations, including the colony board and 6 location cards.

Page 12; note the specific phrasing indicating that other locations are "non-colony locations" thus including the colony as one location just a special location.

> Add 1 zombie to the colony for every 2 survivors (including helpless survivors) present there (rounded up). Add 1 zombie to each non-colony location for every 1 survivor present at that location.

thus the colony IS a location. a single location. The rest of it is a combination of cards saying to add/remove zombies from locations and not entrances.